# Null objects after removing document from jsonstore collection

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

How can I remove objects from collection using remove() function without leaving null objects?
When we delete the object using remove() it will be replaced by null. I don't want to keep the null objects in collection because of memory/performance.

Answer (score 0):

All the production ready versions of the JSONStore API (i.e. iOS, Android, WP8 and Windows 8) remove documents from the persistent store when the document being removed is not marked as dirty. You can use the markClean API to ensure the document is not dirty prior to calling the remove API to really remove it from the persistent store.

If you think there is a defect somewhere you may open a PMR [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639). If want to request new functionality you may open a feature request [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).